# lastIndexOf in JSTL or JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

Can I figure out `lastIndexOf()` function at JSTL or JSP ? 
I just found the method 
 `int indexOf(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)` in JSTL. Or has there anyway to work this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `fn:split` and sum lengths (`fn:length`) of all components excluding the last one.
But it's much better to do all logic in backend, just add additional properties to your object.

Comment: OK guy.. really I want to know easy way to get it. Now I had used JQuery to fix it. My problem is to break as new line in last word. OK.. Thanks for your suggestion ! I will split it in JAVA controller class and iterate them..

Comment: @Cataclysm Create some new method like `public String getFormattedString() {...}` in your object and do everything inside this method only. Then just output as `<c:out value="${yourObject.formattedString}"/>`

Answer (score 5):

can try :

```
<c:set value="${fn:split('fooBar/BarFoo/Bar','/')}" var="separatorPosition" />
     <c:out value="${separatorPosition[fn:length(separatorPosition)-1]}">
   </c:out>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that seems to work for me. Modify myStr and lastIndexOf to what you want.

```
    <!-- Prepare variables -->
    <c:set var="myStr" value="this_is my. string_ok"/>
    <c:set var="lastIndexOf" value="_"/>
    <c:set var="lastIndexFoundAt" value=""/>
    <c:set var="myStrSize" value="${fn:length(myStr) }"/>
    <c:set var="indexIn" value="0"/>
    <c:set var="indexOut" value="1"/>

    <!-- iterate through string -->
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${myStrSize}">

            <c:if test="${indexOut <= myStrSize }">
                <c:set var="char" value="${fn:substring(myStr, indexIn, indexOut) }"/>
                <c:if test="${char == lastIndexOf }">
                    <c:set var="lastIndexFoundAt" value="${i}"/>
                </c:if>

                <c:set var="indexIn" value="${indexIn + 1 }"/> <!-- increment -->
                <c:set var="indexOut" value="${indexOut + 1 }"/> <!-- increment -->
            </c:if>

    </c:forEach>
```

to test the index, use

```
    <c:out value="${lastIndexFoundAt}/>
```